# difference between these two postgreSQL start commands?

Tags: postgresql

Setting up psql for a second time and I came across a guide that told me to use this line to start the server: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`. When before I was taught to use this line: `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

I was wondering what the difference was between the two and if there are advantages to one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are fine.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-start.html)

> Thus, the simplest way to start the server is:
>
> ```
> $ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> $ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
> ```

However, further on the manual also states:

> This shell syntax can get tedious quickly. Therefore the wrapper program `pg_ctl` is provided to simplify some tasks

So it's essentially a matter of taste.